# Problem with the name of an NSEntityDescription

Tags: cocoa, core-data, nspredicate, nsmanagedobject

This problem follows on from a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2467921/what-changes-in-core-data-after-a-save).

When I run the following line of code:

```
NSEntityDescription *outputCellEntityDescription = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"OutputCell"
                                                               inManagedObjectContext:[[self document] managedObjectContext]];
```

I get the following error:

```
HIToolbox: ignoring exception '+entityForName: could not locate an NSManagedObjectModel for entity name 'OutputCell'' that raised inside Carbon event dispatch
```

My concern is the extra uptick that seems to have appeared at the end of the entity name in the error. Can anyone explain why this might occur or how I could go about debugging it. The code runs as normal when it is first run, but after a few Core Data fetches it seems to break. Could it be a problem related to a memory leak or similar?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Does this project have actual Carbon elements?

Comment: I haven't added any but I'm referencing a few open source frameworks. Not sure if they have any.

Comment: It's just an odd error. I haven't seen a mix of Core Data, HIToolbox and a carbon event like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't an extra uptick. You just have nested quotations:

> [']+entityForName: could not locate an
>   NSManagedObjectModel for entity name
>   'OutputCell' [']

This bit is the string returned by the exception. It in turn has `OutputCell` single quoted. It does look confusing though. If you hadn't seen it before it's easy to miss.

Not sure what is causing the error, however.

### Edit:

As a debugging step I suggest logging the results of a call to `-[NSManagedObjectModel entities]` on your model to see if it does actually contain the `OutputCell` entity.

A simple explanation for your problem is that the you somehow switch models after you save. Either you accidentally assign a different model or you nil out the model you have. To test for that you should log the address of the NSManagedObjectModel instance and see if it changes.

Comment: Thanks, should have spotted that one myself.

Comment: Not yet, been trying for a few days but I'm slowly getting there. It seems to be something related to the Core Data model breaking somewhere when it get's fetched.

Comment: You want to be careful about hitting the checkmarks then. I doubt you'll get any more answers to the previous question because people will think it has been resolved.